# I made it to the ship; now what?

Tags: star-wars-kotor-2

In Knights of the Old Replublic II, you wake up in a room and you get out and do the puzzles and fight, etc. I am at the part just after I destroyed the assassin robot on the normal floor of paragus, and have made it into the republic ship with all the dead replublic coprses.

I have made it onto two levels of the ship (presumably all of them) and now have no idea what to do. I have looked in my quests, asked Krei and that other guy you rescue from prison, and they offer no help.

What do I do now?

Comment: It's a bit hard to guess where exactly you're stuck. Have you made it through the mines already?

Answer (score 1):

I am answering this myself because I found the answer and I think this will help others.

What I needed to do was go past my "old room" and use the turbolift near there to get to the command deck, because that turbolift loads a different area.